# In Sublime, why does my node process not exit naturally?

Tags: node.js, sublimetext

When I run my node script in Sublime 3 (as a build system ... Ctrl-B), if I add a listener to the stdin's `data` event, the process stays running until killed. This makes sense, since there's potentially still work to do.

```
process.stdin.on('data', (d)=> {
  // ... do some work with `d`
});
```

However, I expected that if I removed the listener to that data event, my process would naturally exit. But it doesn't!

```
// This program never exits naturally.

function processData(d) {
  // ... do some work with `d`, then...
  process.stdin.removeListener('data', processData);
}
process.stdin.on('data', processData);
```

Even if you remove the event handler immediately after adding it, the process still sticks around...

```
function processData() {}

process.stdin.on('data', processData);
process.stdin.removeListener('data', processData);
```

In this exact case, I could use the `once()` function instead of `on()`, but that doesn't clear this up for me. What am I missing? Why does the stdin stream prevent the process from exiting, given it has no listeners of any kind?

Comment: does it still hold up the process when you send EOF on stdin?

Comment: @randomusername Oh, I checked in the commandline and it *does* exit as expected. That's embarassing. I was running it inside sublime as a build system, so there's something strange going on there. Will edit the question now...